# Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text

Tags: community

```
SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(descp__c), "welcomeback", "_welcomeback")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because of the `TEXT` function and not `SUBSTITUTE` function. As the error message suggests, `TEXT` function expects **Number, Date, DateTime and Picklist** and I assume your field `descp__c's` datatype is none of the above mentioned one hence it is giving the error. You can go through all the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) of salesforce for more information on this.

In your case, you can just use below without TEXT function which should work

```
SUBSTITUTE(descp__c, "welcomeback", "_welcomeback")
```